# /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource folders in Magento?

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to fix some problems with a Magento site, but I'm running into lots of problems . . .

I've located a folder in Magento with the path:

"/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource"

In the default install of Magento it has a file structure like so:

```
 - category
 - collection
 - eav
 - helper
 - layer
 - product
 - more php files
```

However the dump of the current site I've received didn't have any of those folders or files except the "Eav" folder, the site was throwing errors so I added the other folders in (which seemed to fix it) unfortunately I think this may have caused other problems.

My question is, are all of those folders absolutely necessary for Magento to work? Or are there situations in which you might remove all of those folder/files except the "Eav" folder?

Comment: When you say the default install, are you actually comparing the default install of the same version of Magento? A lot of the files now found in Model/Resource was in Model/Mysql4 in older versions of Magento.

Comment: Yes, you were right, I was comparing the recent version to an old version (1.4) where the only folder/file in that directory was "Eav" *facepalm*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a general ORM rework which occurred in CE1.6. Along with the introduction of DB-specific helpers and the completion of the Varien DDL components, the resource models were generally moved to a standard location for all modules. In the case of Mage_Catalog the resource models were moved from *Mage/Catalog/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/* to *Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/* and the resource model class group was changed from `catalog_resource_eav_mysql4` to `catalog_resource`.

As noted in comments above, it is best to compare apples to apples, meaning to verify the version number in the `Mage` class and comparing the core files to a known-good copy.